# edmond karps in Boost Graph Library

Tags: c++, boost, graph-algorithm, max-flow

A part of my algorithm requires to compute maximum flow in a network with integer capacities. I want to use boost::edmonds_karp_max_flow algorithm to find the maximum flow.

I tried reading the documentation but it was very difficult for me as I have never used BGL before. I have created the graph as follows where the weight attribute of the `Edge` must be used as capacity of the edges in the graph.

```
struct Vertex{
    int id;
    bool flag;
};
struct Edge{
    int weight;
};
 typedef boost::adjacency_list<  
    boost::listS,               
    boost::vecS,                
    boost::undirectedS,         
    Vertex,                     
    Edge                        
 >MyGraph;
```

My goal is to write the following function

```
 int max_flow( const MyGraph& gr, int u, int v) {
       // compute the maximum flow between vertices with ids u,v
 }
```

can someone show me with an example how to implement this function ?

Comment: there is an example here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/graph/example/edmonds-karp-eg.cpp

Comment: You can see sample of this function in my recent post (in c++): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445400/missing-some-paths-in-edmonds-karp-max-flow-algorithm